# How to match some text preceded by any other text

Tags: java, regex

How can I match "`Because it already exists`" with regex in string below :

```
<faultstring>Error has occured! Reason why: Because it already exists. request id: 443p3-34356a</faultstring>
```

This expressio fails :

```
(.+)+Because it already exists(.+)+
```

I need to match `<faultstring></faultstring>` as well, so I need to match `Because it already exists` inside faulstring opening and closing  tags

**note:**

This is a multiline string, I just printed out this one it is important.

Comment: Also, you can try http://www.rexv.org/ to easily evaluate regexps against source text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More simply :

```
/Because it already exists/
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you want those outer pluses.

```
(.+)Because it already exists(.+)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [this online regular expression tester](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm), I found that [Borealid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254367/how-to-match-some-text-preceded-by-any-other-text/3254380#3254380) reply totally fulfills your need.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you ask:

```
(?<=.+)Because it already exists(?=.+)
```

However it looks like you are doing something unusual and there is probably a better way to do it.

What are you trying to do?